# Can't access Flask API on Heroku Due to CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, heroku, flask, cors

I'm attempting to make a call to my flask api (hosted on Heroku). It works when I put the url in the url bar, but not when I implement it via jquery it fails.

I went ahead and installed [flask-cors](http://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and added the following:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
@cross_origin()
def home():
    return jsonify({"results":{}})
```

Is there something else I have to do? I also did the following in my request:

```
function fetchResults(requestURL, callback) {

    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {  
            if (xmlHttp.status === 200) {   
                callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
            } else {  
                console.error("Error: " + xmlHttp.status + xmlHttp.statusText);  
            }  
        }  
    }

    //Make Async GET Request
    xmlHttp.open("GET", requestURL, true); 
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is the header you should set in responses not requests. and the `cross_origin` does that for you.

if you want to use JQuery just use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    ....,
    crossDomain: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks Mehdy. However I'd like to use an xmlhttprequest (I've posted my full javascript function). I've removed the header from the request as you suggested, but I'm still seeing the same problem which is being logged as: `Failed to load resource: Cannot make any requests from null.`

Comment: oh! I see! just don't pass `null` to the send function! just `xmlHttp.send()`

Comment: I just test it and it works. the error is obviously because of the request and has nothing to do with CORS. so just make sure you're providing a valid request URL.

Comment: How did you test it @mehdy? If I copy and paste the requestURL in the url bar it works. However it does not work when it is implemented as shown above. With that said, if I click on `Disable Cross Origin Restrictions` in Safari's Develop menu, my example above works, meaning it's a CORS problem.

Comment: Woah. I think it's a [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136081) in Safari. My API does not require authentication. I found it works in firefox.